# What is the easiest way to kill mobs automatically in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing minecraft one day, and I was wondering if there was any good method to protecting my house automatically (While not using Golems!) from angry mobs. Is there any way to install a system that protects my house from evil baddies?

Comment: with or without mods?

Comment: There are several ways, many will be more or less practical based on your biome.  Example, planting cactus all around will help prevent spiders climbing walls (ideal for sandy areas), planting sugar cane will prevent archer arrows, and having a pit around your house can trap other mobs (ideal for flatter areas).  The hardest mob to protect against is likely going to be endermen who can teleport, though they do tend to avoid water (if you've ever seen them going crazy when it rains).  Eric mentioned a lava moat, though if you live in the forest all the trees might burn down.

Comment: @Batophobia This sounds like it should be an answer.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms Very well.  I expanded on it a bit.

Comment: @Rapitor Whichever works best

Comment: @Sparow the current answer is probably the best for no-mod setup. If you'd like to know some ways to do it with mods (feed the beast, tekkit, yogbox, etc) I'd suggest a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is fairly broad.  Home security is going to need several different pieces to deal with the different behaviors of the different mobs.  Additionally, if you care about the defenses "fitting in" to the overall look of your home/biome, then some solutions may not be acceptable.  Furthermore, some biomes can have more options, for example deserts can take advantage of the sand and it's obeying gravity.  Despite those, here are some suggestions.

**General guidelines**
The best way to prevent [spawning monsters](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Mob_spawning) is to light the place up.

> the light level of the spawning block must be 7 or darker

Another good way to prevent monsters from coming close is to put a fence around your land.  Spiders can climb fences and Endermen have a chance of teleporting, but other mobs will be stuck.  However, skeletons can shoot over the fence.

Yet another option would be to build upward.  Make your main level a couple blocks above the ground and bring the outer walls down.  This way mobs are stuck below your door without falling into anything.

Alternatively, you can just dig a trench that enemies cannot jump out of.  Or even make one deep enough that the [fall damage](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Damage#Fall_damage) kills the enemies.  The [damage formula](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10218/42984) is `(# blocks) - 3 = damage`

Additionally, redstone can make for some [creative solutions to protecting your home](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93572/42984).  With the addition of the [daylight sensor](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Daylight_Sensor) you can even have defenses only active at night.

**Spiders** can climb walls, so we need to figure out how to stop that.  [Spiders cannot climb over signs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/77315/42984).  You could also [include a lip or ladder at the top of the wall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14574/42984).  Since spiders are 2 wide and 2 long, planting cactus around your house will damage spiders as well, though I believe you need to add extra to the top if you want to fully kill it before it crosses the top.

**Skeletons** shoot arrows.  Sugar cane used to be able to block projectiles, but that has been patched.  You can use glass in your windows to avoid taking damage inside your house.  To avoid them reaching your house, you can use a ditch or moat similar to zombie/creeper defenses.

**Endermen** hate water (and lava), though they are normally neutral.  If you can cover spaces around your house with water, that can help prevent them from teleporting near.  They also require and area [3 blocks tall](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/31105/42984), so having a roof can prevent their teleporting/spawning.

**Creepers** [hate cats, cannot destroy obsidian, and do not damage blocks when in water](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/56088/42984).

**Witches** are kind of like smarter zombies.  When damaged, they try to heal.  When under water, they drink potion of water-breathing.  When on fire, they drink potion of fire resistance.  They also use splash potions as weapons, making them ranged enemies.  Best option here is probably to just use a ditch and get them stuck.

**Zombies** come in many shapes and sizes.  Some can even fit through a 1 block hole.  To defend against them, you can have a moat of that directs them away from your door, have a moat of lava that kills them, or have a pit that traps them.

**Slime** is unlikely to be bothering you, but if you have some problems with them they can mostly be dealt with similar to zombies.

Comment: one thing about slimes, the most likely place to find slimes and witches is swamps, so if you avoid building near a swamp, that would take care of those two mobs

Comment: @jc3833 Witches now spawn regularly at night. Which is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Lava around your house works for zombies a lot of the time.

Comment: While this is certainly a solution, we often prefer answers to be more detailed.  Could you please expand your answer by including things such as distance to the house, depth, etc.?